# PHP displaying rows

Tags: php, mysql

Still new to PHP. I'd like to display few rows from database using ID's stored in the array. Actually it displays only the first row (with ID=2) and i'm looking for the way to display all of them (4 rows).

```
$i=0;
if($sql1= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table"))
{
  $arr = array(2,3,5,7);
  $sql2= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='".$arr[$i]."'");
  while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2)) 
  {
    echo $row1['id'];
    echo $row1['content'];  //display some rows
    $i=$i+1; 
  }
}
```

Anyone know how to achieve that?

Comment: Looks like you're doing OK so far - what's the problem?

Comment: you need to normalize your db; kind of sounds like you have comma-separated values. If not, then use `IN()` or `FIND_IN_SET()`. Question's unclear as to what the values are in db.

Comment: as @JayBlanchard said; what seems to be the problem? or have you left the question or not bothering with comments asking for clarification?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is you use an array, but never loop through the elements. Also, instead of executing the query multiple times, you could get the results with a single query:

```
$i=0;
if($sql1= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table"))
{
    $arr = array(2,3,5,7);
    $ids = implode(',',$arr);
    $sql2= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id in (".$ids.")");
    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2)) {
        echo $row1['id'];
        echo $row1['content'];  //display some rows
        $i=$i+1; 
    }
}
```

If you actually need to loop through the array, you could do that like this:

```
if($sql1= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table"))
{
    $arr = array(2,3,5,7);
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($arr);$i++) {
        $sql2= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='".$arr[$i]."'");
        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2)) {
            echo $row1['id'];
            echo $row1['content'];  //display some rows
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works! Thanks for the new knowledge!